# Kafka cluster mode ports configuration

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I'm trying to deploy a docker kafka cluster with 3 zookeeper and 3 kafka nodes. The kafka nodes keeps dying printing the following errors:

```
[main-SendThread(zookeeper-1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zookeeper-1/10.0.0.5:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(zookeeper-1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to zookeeper-1/10.0.0.5:2181, initiating session
[main-SendThread(zookeeper-1:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

While the zookeeper nodes keeps printing:

```
WARN Cannot open channel to 1 at election address
zookeeper-1/10.0.0.5:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:558)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:610)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:838)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:957)
    [2019-03-01 17:24:30,930] INFO Resolved hostname: zookeeper-1 to address: zookeeper-1/10.0.0.5 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
    [2019-03-01 17:24:30,931] WARN Cannot open channel to 2 at election address zookeeper-2/10.0.0.7:3888 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager)
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:558)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:610)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:838)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:957)
```

It looks like the zookeeper nodes cannot communicate each other, but I checked several times the docker-compose yaml and I cannot find the odd. Can somebody help me?

The docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  kafka_example:
    driver: overlay

services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
    volumes:
      - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-1/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
      - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-1/zookeeper_etc:/etc/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:2888:3888;zookeeper-2:2888:3888;zookeeper-3:2888:3888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
    networks:
      - kafka_example

  zookeeper-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
    volumes:
      - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-2/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
      - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-2/zookeeper_etc:/etc/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:2888:3888;zookeeper-2:2888:3888;zookeeper-3:2888:3888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
    networks:
      - kafka_example

  zookeeper-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
    volumes:
      - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-3/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
      - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-3/zookeeper_etc:/etc/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:2888:3888;zookeeper-2:2888:3888;zookeeper-3:2888:3888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
    networks:
      - kafka_example

  message_queue_kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
    volumes:
      - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-1/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data:rw'  # mount point
      - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-1/kafka_etc:/etc/kafka:rw'
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://message_queue_kafka-1:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
      KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS: 20000
      KAFKA_REBALANCE_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    networks:
      - kafka_example

  message_queue_kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
    volumes:
      - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-2/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data:rw'  # mount point
      - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-2/kafka_etc:/etc/kafka:rw'
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://message_queue_kafka-2:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
      KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS: 20000
      KAFKA_REBALANCE_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    networks:
      - kafka_example

  message_queue_kafka-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
    volumes:
      - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-3/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data:rw'  # mount point
      - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-3/kafka_etc:/etc/kafka:rw'
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://message_queue_kafka-3:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
      KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS: 20000
      KAFKA_REBALANCE_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    networks:
      - kafka_example
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the odd here: https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-get-zookeeper-to-work-running-in-docker-using-swarm-mode/27109/2

To let zookeeper cluster work, it seems, you need to specify 0.0.0.0 as hostname x when KAFKA_BROKER_ID is x. It also seems it doesn't matter the port numbers since they are different machines (virtually).

Here it is my new compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  kafka_example:
      driver: overlay

services:
  zookeeper-1:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
      volumes:
        - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-1/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper:rw'
        - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-1/zookeeper_etc:/etc/zookeeper:rw'
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: 0.0.0.0:2888:3888;zookeeper-2:2888:3888;zookeeper-3:2888:3888
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
        ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
        ZOOKEEPER_MAX_CLIENT_CNXNS: 200
      networks:
      - kafka_example

  zookeeper-2:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
      volumes:
        - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-2/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper:rw'
        - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-2/zookeeper_etc:/etc/zookeeper:rw'
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:2888:3888;0.0.0.0:2888:3888;zookeeper-3:2888:3888
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
        ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
        ZOOKEEPER_MAX_CLIENT_CNXNS: 200
      networks:
        - kafka_example

  zookeeper-3:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
      volumes:
        - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-3/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper:rw'
        - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-3/zookeeper_etc:/etc/zookeeper:rw'
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:2888:3888;zookeeper-2:2888:3888;0.0.0.0:2888:3888
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
        ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
        ZOOKEEPER_MAX_CLIENT_CNXNS: 200
      networks:
        - kafka_example

  message_queue_kafka-1:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
      volumes:
        - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-1/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data:rw'
        - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-1/kafka_etc:/etc/kafka:rw'
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://message_queue_kafka-1:9092
        KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
        KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS: 20000
        KAFKA_REBALANCE_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper-1
        - zookeeper-2
        - zookeeper-3
      networks:
        - kafka_example

  message_queue_kafka-2:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
      volumes:
        - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-2/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data:rw'
        - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-2/kafka_etc:/etc/kafka:rw'
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://message_queue_kafka-2:9092
        KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
        KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS: 20000
        KAFKA_REBALANCE_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper-1
        - zookeeper-2
        - zookeeper-3
      networks:
        - kafka_example

  message_queue_kafka-3:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
      volumes:
        - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-3/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data:rw'
        - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-3/kafka_etc:/etc/kafka:rw'
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://message_queue_kafka-3:9092
        KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
        KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS: 20000
        KAFKA_REBALANCE_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper-1
        - zookeeper-2
        - zookeeper-3
      networks:
        - kafka_example
```

Comment: This is odd since I never had to do this. Also different to the examples found in the confluent repo. Anyways glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup, 3 zookeepers, and 3 brokers and it's working nicely. I noticed three things, from your setup that are different to mine and the second one I know for sure is a problem (I did the same and was not working)

1. For `ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS` you are using the same port combination for all the zookeepers `2888:3888`. From what I know you should have different ports [check this example as a reference](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.1.2-post/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml).
2. You are using the same `ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT` for all your zookeeper instances, consider using a different one for each instance, and also different to the port used in `ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS`.
3. For the kafka services, the value for the environmental variable `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT` is quoted in single quotes, I *don't think this is a problem* but is a bit inconsistent with the rest of your configuration.

Consider then changing the values for `ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS` and `ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT`, for example to something like this:

```
ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
```

And also remember to adjust the value for `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT` accordingly:

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
```

> **clientPort** the port to listen for client connections
>
> **server.X** ..., note the two port numbers after each server name: " 2888" and "3888". Peers use the former port to connect to other peers. Such a connection is necessary so that peers can communicate, for example, to agree upon the order of updates. More specifically, a ZooKeeper server uses this port to connect followers to the leader. When a new leader arises, a follower opens a TCP connection to the leader using this port. Because the default leader election also uses TCP, we currently require another port for leader election. This is the second port in the server entry.

Extract from [Zookeeper Docs](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.4-beta/zookeeperStarted.html)

All together should look something like this (did not test it yet):

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
kafka_example:
    driver: overlay

services:
zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
    volumes:
    - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-1/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
    - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-1/zookeeper_etc:/etc/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
    environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
    ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
    networks:
    - kafka_example

zookeeper-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
    volumes:
    - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-2/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
    - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-2/zookeeper_etc:/etc/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
    environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
    ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
    networks:
    - kafka_example

zookeeper-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1
    volumes:
    - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-3/zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
    - '/volumedockerkafka/zookeeper-3/zookeeper_etc:/etc/zookeeper:rw'  # mount point
    environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 42181
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
    ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
    networks:
    - kafka_example

message_queue_kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
    volumes:
    - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-1/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data:rw'  # mount point
    - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-1/kafka_etc:/etc/kafka:rw'
    environment:
    KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS: '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/json_log4j.properties'
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://message_queue_kafka-1:9092
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
    KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS: 20000
    KAFKA_REBALANCE_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper-1
    - zookeeper-2
    - zookeeper-3
    networks:
    - kafka_example

message_queue_kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
    volumes:
    - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-2/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data:rw'  # mount point
    - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-2/kafka_etc:/etc/kafka:rw'
    environment:
    KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS: '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/json_log4j.properties'
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://message_queue_kafka-2:9092
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2ori
    KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
    KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS: 20000
    KAFKA_REBALANCE_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper-1
    - zookeeper-2
    - zookeeper-3
    networks:
    - kafka_example

message_queue_kafka-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.1
    volumes:
    - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-3/kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data:rw'  # mount point
    - '/volumedockerkafka/kafka-3/kafka_etc:/etc/kafka:rw'
    environment:
    KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS: '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/json_log4j.properties'
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://message_queue_kafka-3:9092
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
    KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
    KAFKA_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS: 20000
    KAFKA_REBALANCE_TIMEOUT_MS: 300000
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper-1
    - zookeeper-2
    - zookeeper-3
    networks:
    - kafka_example
```

**UPDATE**

This is the docker-compose I'm using, in my setup the containers can are in any of two physical hosts.

```
version: '2'
services:
zookeeper-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.1
    environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: '42181'
    ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: '5'
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: '3'
    ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: '2'
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: '2000'
zookeeper-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.1
    environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: '32181'
    ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: '5'
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: '2'
    ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: '2'
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: '2000'
zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.1
    environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: '22181'
    ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: '5'
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:22888:23888;zookeeper-2:32888:33888;zookeeper-3:42888:43888
    ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: '1'
    ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: '2'
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: '2000'
kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.1.1
    environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:19092
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '1'
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
    KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: '0'
kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.1.1
    environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-2:29092
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '2'
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
    KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: '0'
kafka-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.1.1
    environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-3:39092
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: '3'
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:22181,zookeeper-2:32181,zookeeper-3:42181
    KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: '0'
```

Comment: I've tried your changes and, a part some identation errors, it gives me the same error as before. Which version of compose are you using? The documentation you linked is for 2 but I'm using 3.3

Comment: I also would understand,if I use the same port on zookeeper-1 and zookeeper-2, this should not be a problem since I'm not publishing them on the same port, isn't it?

Comment: The compose version I'm using is 2, but this is because I'm running the cluster in rancher. Will try in my local with version 3 and post my docker compose here.